# User cannot edit list item even with correct permisions

Tags: list, workflow, permissions, access-denied, access

I am very new to SharePoint and am setting up a vacation approval process with a calendar. The workflow works fine for me. But the users who need to be able to "Approve/Deny" the request get "access denied" when trying to either edit the item to change the status, or when using the custom workflow I made that updates the fields in a more user friendly way.

I given the users contribute access to the list and workflow. I have confirmed the issue by having a user request access. Upon granting access the user still could not edit the item.

Thank you!

Comment: Do they have contribute permissions on the task list as well?

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked all the permissions and they have contribute permissions on the task list.

Comment: What are the item level permissions set as in the Advanced Settings of the calendar list?

Comment: Edit access was set to "only their own." I changed it to "all items" but the same issue has occurred.

Comment: Another user was able to edit the item and "accept". How could it be localized?